Migrate Active Directory integrated DNS to Infoblox
I have two Active Directory domain controllers with DNS service.
I migrated the DHCP service to Infoblox. Now I need migrate the DNS service.
How can the DNS records be updated dynamically in Infoblox after using the Data Import Wizard to export the records to infoblox?
After this configuration, will user authentication continue to work?
If there is a need to put more machines in the domain, will it work by directing DNS to the Infoblox IP?

AD is built over DNS, it's not a good idea to remove it, you should think more to add a DNS partner between the AD and Infoblox.

@yagmoth555 (and others): https://www.techopedia.com/2/31981/networking/networking-hardware/dismissing-the-myth-that-active-directory-requires-microsoft-dns#the-microsoft-myth

@Stygge I just said it's not a good idea to remove, as the article is right, but if you change tech or hire someone to debug your IT structure it's hard to find someone that are a guru in Windows and on Linux at the same time (if you use like bind), thus you are bringing to your enterprise a IT burden IMO. The DNS's role is lightweight, I dont see how to keep the admin console there for a replication with another DNS is a bad idea.

Infoblox has much greater capabilities than Windows DNS.  I would keep the bits around, but would not mess with keeping them replicated. THAT is much more complicated.  Infoblox has several KBs about this process, have you reviewed any of them?

https://serverfault.com/questions/980396/migrating-from-microsoft-ad-integrated-dns-to-infoblox
